# How to use a global config value in a private config file with symfony2

Tags: symfony

I defined some values in the define.yml in the app/config folder.
And I can access then in the PHP code.
Now I want to use the validate.yml file to check weather users give out too many data, could I use the configed valus in the config file(such as %maxInputLength%) rather than write it one more time in the 
validate.yml?

for a example:
I defind a variable in define.yml:
`maxLength: 10`
So we can use it in the controller.

But if I want to use it in the validate.yml in my own bundle,
such as : myBandle/config/validation.yml
Now I just use the file like that:

```
 myBundle\Entity\UserDesc:  
    properties:  
        content:  
            - NotBlank: ~  
            - MaxLength: 10
```

So it seems that the same value was defined at two place.In fact the 10 in the second file is just the value defined in the first file . But I don't know how to get the value from the first file.Is there any way to make that?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Post the code revelant to the question, the files you included and an example of your **desired output**. It will help us helping you

Comment: Quite sorry for that,I append some new content to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you want to set value to variable in one config file and then reuse it in other .yml config file.

So you cant define some vars in e.g variables.yml file

```
parameters:
    test_variable: "blabla"
```

Then in second .yml config file you can import file with defined variables:

```
imports:
    - { resource: variables.yml }
```

Then you can use imported variable in this file:

```
property:
    some_value: %test_variable%
```

Comment: Yes, this quite works for  the second.yml **IS NOT** a file use to validation.However it seems in validation.yml , the `imports:` does not work.Now I use a validation.yml file for both validation and parse it in the code myself rather than use the getParaments(). If you get other method to set the configuration in the file in app/config and use it in the  validation.yml of the private bundle, Please teach me.